# MongoDB - Find numbers that starts with a string

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to make a query that gets all the prices that starts with '12'.
I have a collection like this:

```
{
  "place": "Costa Rica", 
  "name": "Villa Lapas",
  "price": 1353,
},
{
  "place": "Costa Rica", 
  "name": "Hotel NWS",
  "price": 1948,
},
{
  "place": "Costa Rica", 
  "name": "Hotel Papaya",
  "price": 1283,
},
{
 "place": "Costa Rica", 
 "name": "Hostal Serine",
 "price": 1248,
},
```

And I want my results like this:

```
 {
  'prices': [
      1248,
      1283
   ]
 }
```

I'm converting all the prices to string in order to use a regex function. But I don't understand very well how to use the regex in my query.
My query returns:

```
{ "prices" : null }
{ "prices" : null }
```

Could someone please guide me? :)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {'$project': {
      '_id': 0,
      'price': {'$toString': '$price'}
  }},
  {'$project': {
      'prices': {'$regexFind': { 'input': "$price", 'regex': '^12' }}
  }}
]).pretty();
```

Comment: Your price is a number, so you can't use regexp, regexp works on strings. *prices that starts with '12'* >> do you mean that 12, 123, 1234, 12345 should all match or just 1234

Comment: @thammada.ts OP tried changing to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {'$project': {
      '_id': 0,
      'prices': {'$toString': '$price'}
          ^^^ -> I meant this
  }},
  {'$match': {
      'prices': {'$regex': '^12' }
          ^^^ -> same here
  }}
])
```

You need to use `$match` with `$regex` which yields the result as you expected.

If you use `regexFind`, it works on all matching docs and returns `null` where input doesn't match the pattern

And

In the first `project` you have `price` instead `prices`. If you refer the first `project` name in the second `project`, then pipeline matches.